# VisualForce page dont show custom fields that are not shown on Lead Layout

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

i'm new to VF. I try to add a VF block in the standard Lead Layout.
I have created new custom fields and they ONLY show in the VF block if they are also placed in the standard Lead Layout.
I want them to only appear on the VF block because i want to arrange them in certain way that is not possible with std. Laad Layout.
Any pointers how to have them only in VF?

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to add visualforce page to page layout(inline visualforce page)? if yes then you can easily remove those fields which you don't want to show on page layout and add them only to visualforce page.

Also if you are changing edit layout then I think you can not remove some fields from layout, such as required fields,etc.

Salesforce standard fields cannot be deleted. However, many standard fields can be removed from a page layout. 
To remove a standard field from a page layout, please follow the steps below:

1. Click on:

   - Non-Enhanced Setup Menu - Setup | App Setup | Customize |
   - Enhanced Setup Menu - Setup | Build | Customize |
2. Click on the name of the Page Layout and select "Edit".
3. Click and drag the field from the layout into the box on the top of the page layout editor
4. Click "Save".

see for more information:
https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000003629&language=en_US

Hope this helps.

Comment: ohh yes, Thank you Teepeemm. I will remember this going forward. I am new here. Thankx. I will edit my answer.